# How to call SAP GW create_deep_entity method() in SAP WebIDE?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-web-ide, sap-gateway

I have been using Web IDE trial version to try out one application.
The application needs to pass data to Gateway method Create Deep Entity.

While using oModel.create() getting an error which says method not implemented (i.e. Plain create method is called with oModel.create(), which is not implemented on SAP Gateway. but what I need to call is create_deep_entity method )

Just need to know is there any syntax that will tell Web IDE that Deep Create is to be called.

Comment: Please show us the concrete oModel.create() call. It really has to be a deep create, e.g.: `oModel.create({field1: '', field2: 0, childEntity: {field3: 'ABC'}})`;

Answer (score 0):

there is not a create_deep entity method as such in SAPUI5. If your deep insert is correctly implemented on SAP Gateway, you just need to  use a standard create or post mehod on sapui5 with the difference that the data you are sending will not have a flat structure. See the example of @serban Petrscu.

```
oModel.create({field1: '', field2: 0, childEntity: {field3: 'ABC'}})
```